# use variable of a class in view controller file in ios

Tags: ios

I have a model, and I am not being able to use it in view controller. Keep getting the legendary SIGABRT error.

My model:

[image: my model]

My view controller"

[image: my view controller]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the error...

Comment: Even if - don't post pictures of code and error messages, post the text directly here on SO instead.